# Looping over an array subsection with modulus?

Tags: c

I have a large array, and a number of operations which loop over the last N elements of it, where N is different in each case. There's an index variable for each of these, and each index is updated at irregular intervals,at which time its position is incremented by one element. (The array is an audio buffer, and the operations are copying different parts of it to output).

So a normal loop construct isn't possible.

Previously, I was looping over the whole array, so each time an index was updated, I could simply test its value with a mod operation using the length of the array, and reset if necessary. I *think* I need something similar, but incorporating an offset to reset the index to (array_size - N), rather than to zero.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this - sorry if I'm missing the blindingly obvious!

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you need? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Sorry folks, I realise I put the question badly, because a for loop isn't possible. Just posting this quickly to stop anybody else wasting their time  - I'll edit the question asap.

Comment: It sounds like you may be doing granular synthesis or running many delay lines in parallel. If so, you should think carefully about the operations that you need to perform and design your algorithm to minimize computational complexity. It may be efficient to have a single master loop and counter with many internal counters for each audio suboperation.

Comment: That was a very accurate diagnosis :) - yes, I'm doing both. And your description of a master buffer/counter and many sub-counters is pretty much what I'm trying to do, having realised that multiple buffers don't scale well!

Answer (score 3):

```
// loop over last N 

sometype array[maxsize];

for (sometype* p = array + maxsize - N; p < array + maxsize; ++p)
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( unsigned int i = std::max( 0u, array.size() - N ); i < array.size(); ++i )
```

?

Comment: plz2formatUrPosts! You've had 2 years and 3 months to learn how.

Comment: I just saw you wrote `You've`. Is that correct grammatically?

Comment: Actually I've been doing more than posting on stackoverflow in these 2 years & 3 months, but I'm going to put in the effort in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What about a `for` loop starting from the end, for example like this:

```
for ( int i = array_size; (i >= 0) && (i >= (array_size - N)); i-- )
    operation( array[i] );
```

You probably don't need the modulo operator for something like that, unless I don't understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length of the array this is easy

```
int L=length;
int* array;

int* start=array+length-N;
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
   doSomething( start[i] );
}
```

If you are looking for a modulo operator, use `%`

```
int i=0;
while(condition){
  i++; i%=N; // increment i, modulo N
}
```